# mysql update statement using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I am developing a database on online quiz management

- one table stdinfo stores usernames and student details
- table testinfo stores the testid name subjects and their marking schemes(separate for each subject) in form of multiple rows like

[image: see this]

- and one table question has all the questions with their qids
- and one table records the responses of students

Now there is a column marks in responses which displays the marks obtained in that question.

Since i want to generate the result i have already inserted the responses and their ids/usernames. Now i want to insert marks for calculate result;

what it should do

- set marks=0 where the response is null ;
- set marks=posmark obtained from the testinfo table for respective subject if the response is correct
- set marks=negmark obtained from the testinfo table for respective subject if the response is incorrect

table structures are given below;

[image: responses]
[image: testinfo]
[image: question]

Comment: why is this entire question formatted as a quote?

Comment: Why are you posting text as pictures? Please use plain text in code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the answer for your question [here][1]  https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85816#msg-85816

or look at this:

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN b USING (id)
SET a.firstname='Pekka', a.lastname='Kuronen',
b.companyname='Suomi Oy',companyaddress='Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi'
WHERE a.id=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm reposting the answer in a more elaborate manner since my prevoius answer was deleted.

I found it myself and also found the answer by @Jirka49 helpful. See link below.

[See the last section in the webpage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

So, we need to avoid the use of the IN operator.

So create a temporary table during the query which contains details of the questions,test information and question information(the positive marks) wherever the student has answered correctly.

Now use this table to update the responses table by where clause.

So the query becomes:

```
  update responses,
(select posmark,responses.testid,responses.qid,responses.stid from testinfo,responses,question
 where testinfo.testid=responses.testid and responses.testid="<whatever testid>" and question.qid=responses.qid and question.cans=responses.response and question.subcode=testinfo.subcode and responses.stid='<for whichever student>')as temp
 set responses.marks=temp.posmark where responses.qid=temp.qid and temp.testid=responses.testid and responses.stid=temp.stid;
```

Similar thing can be done for negative marks too. And check wheverever answers are null a simple query will assign zero marks.